# FD_SET reading from invalid memory address?

Tags: c, select, pipe

****EDIT: I have found a solution.****

I have a strange problem for those who dare to read below:

I'm working on a homework assignment, and need to send messages between processes using UNIX pipes.

My intention with this code is to select() on the provided file descriptor. If something is available to read without blocking, I want to return it. If not, I want to return NULL and continue without blocking.

Here's the code inside of my "getMessage" function, where fd is the file descriptor:

```
message* getMessage(int fd){
    int messageAvailable = 0;
    struct timeval timeout;
    fd_set fd2;

    //If there's a message available, read it; if not, continue on without delay
    timeout.tv_sec = 0;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;
    FD_ZERO(&fd2);
    FD_SET(fd,&fd2);
    messageAvailable = select(FD_SETSIZE,&fd2,NULL,NULL,&timeout);
    if(messageAvailable){
        int bytesRead = 0;
        message* m;
        m = malloc(sizeof(message));
        //Get the header
        bytesRead = read(fd,m,sizeof(message));
        //If we got the whole message
        if(bytesRead == sizeof(message)){
            return m;
        }else{
            //If a message wasn't generated, free the space we allocated for it
            free(m);
            return NULL;
        }
    }else{
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

This code is inside of a loop that continues for the duration of the program, and at precisely the same point (the next getMessage() call after one message is successfully transferred) it segfaults. Apparently the FD_SET line is reading from an invalid memory location.

Without posting all of my code, can anyone take a guess at what could be happening that's causing a segfault in this simple macro?

I've posted relevant debugging information below, where line 33 corresponds with the FD_SET line above:

```
==1330== Invalid read of size 1
==1330==    at 0x804E819: getMessage (messages.c:33)
==1330==    by 0x8049123: main (messageTest.c:110)
==1330==  Address 0xde88d627 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==1330== 
==1330== 
==1330== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==1330==  Access not within mapped region at address 0xDE88D627
==1330==    at 0x804E819: getMessage (messages.c:33)
==1330==    by 0x8049123: main (messageTest.c:110)
==1330==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==1330==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==1330==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==1330==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==1330==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==1330== 
==1330== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1330==     in use at exit: 344 bytes in 10 blocks
==1330==   total heap usage: 25 allocs, 15 frees, 2,492 bytes allocated
==1330== 
==1330== LEAK SUMMARY:
==1330==    definitely lost: 12 bytes in 1 blocks
==1330==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1330==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1330==    still reachable: 332 bytes in 9 blocks
==1330==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1330== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==1330== 
==1330== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==1330== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 11 from 6)
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Can post more of the code, I can see nothing obviously wrong with what is posted. With the exception that if `select()` fails it returns `-1` and the `if (messageAvailable)` will evaluate to `true`: change to `if (messageAvailable > 0)`. Why not `fd + `1 for first argument to `select()`?

Comment: Yeah... Quite an ambiguous question; I'm sorry about that. However, I've found the solution. Turns out I was passing an invalid file descriptor into getMessage.

And good point about my messageAvailable guard; I'll change it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Oops... I had been accidentally passing -1 into the function as the FD after I did some processing (which explains why it happened at the same point in every run).

This question can probably be closed; I don't think it serves much purpose outside of my single usage case.